# php keep dynamically generated radio button checked after submit

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I know there are other topics covering this, but I read through them, tried the solutions, and am still running into issues.

I have an array, $genderValues, that I loop through in order to echo two radio buttons inside of a form. The form has other inputs with validation. When the user checks male or female, I want that radio button to remain checked when they try to submit the form but fail to meet other validation, rather than having it clear itself.

```
$genderValues = ['Male','Female'];

function ending ($genderVal) {

        if (isset($_POST['gender']) && ($_POST['gender'] == $genderVal)) {
            $ending = " checked />";
                return $ending;
        }
        else{
            $ending = "/>";
            return $ending;
         }
    }

    foreach($genderValues as $genderVal){

        echo "<label class='radio' for=" . $genderVal . ">" . $genderVal . "</label>
        <input type='radio' name='gender' id=" . $genderVal . " value=" . $genderVal . ending($genderVal);

    }
```

Comment: question is not clear . Can you update it ??

Comment: @Drudge Ok, I did. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<input type='radio' name='gender' id=" . $genderVal . " value=" . $genderVal . ending($genderVal);
```

To this:

```
<input type='radio' name='gender' id=" . $genderVal . " value='" . $genderVal . "' " . ending($genderVal);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I originally tried doing something like that before, but when I found my code working without putting the value inside of quotes, I just figured php was being smart and figuring that out for itself. Is it best practice to do the same for the id?